# Get data from Workspace in Azure ML Studio

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I have a problem with connecting to workspace in Azure ML Studio. I am using library `azuremlsdk`, but it doesn't work.
My code looks like:

```
library(azuremlsdk)
workspace_name = 'workspace_name'
subscription_id = 'subscription_id'
resource_group = 'resource_group'
ws <- get_workspace(name = workspace_name, subscription_id = subscription_id, resource_group = resource_group)

dataSet <- get_dataset_by_name(ws, name = "registration_name", version = "latest")
```

After I run that code I get error:
[image]

I have know idea what is wrong. I tried to do it in python and it works fine with the same parameters, code:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = 'subscription_id'
resource_group = 'resource_group'
workspace_name = 'workspace_name'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='registration_name')
```

Any idea how can I fix that bug?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue and got the solution. Follow the below procedure to access the dataset contents from the workspace.

```
data.set <-data.frame(installed.packages("azuremlsdk"));
data.set <-data.frame(installed.packages("remotes"));
remotes::install_cran('azuremlsdk', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))
library(azuremlsdk)
ws <- get_workspace(name = workspace_name, subscription_id = subscription_id, resource_group = resource_group, auth = authentication)
print(ws)
dataSet <- get_dataset_by_name(ws, name = "registration_name", version = "latest")

dataSet
```

[image]